# Logistic regression - predict tree disease probability based on state of nearby trees

Tags: regression, logistic, autocorrelation

I have a dataset of trees, each with a location and a binary variable that indicates whether the tree is sick. I would like to predict the probability of a tree being sick at a location as dependent on the probability of trees at a radius of some kilometers from its location. My question is whether it defies model assumptions.

Comment: Your outcome ($y$) variable is evident: tree is either sick or not (though there is an argument that not all degrees of sickness are equal). What would your features ($X$) be?

Comment: Dave: The idea is to estimate the state of the tree based on nearby trees, so e.g. a factor can be that 75% of the trees around are sick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue would be that you have data from multiple nearby trees, the observations would be independent. I'd say you'd have no problem in this respect, if you took 1000 trees from 1000 different forests (only one tree per forest with forests separated by at least some minimum distance) and had the count of nearby diseased trees as a predictor. If instead, you have data that is at least partially with multiple records from trees in the same location, you have a dependence in the data that would make you overestimate how much evidence you have for your findings unless you account for this. Using some spatial correlation structures to account for the correlation in predictors and outcomes in the data would seem necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a common term for this bias? I have one big forest and need to understand how severe the issue is. Autoregressive spatial models for my specific needs would be pretty exotic